# How to use extension-method that uses interface

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

So i'm trying to make a static class called ActionExtensions which has a body like this:

```
public static class ActionExtensions {
        public static IContainer Add<TObjectType>(this IContainer container, TObjectType obj) {
            return container;
        }
}
```

and uses interface IContainer.
I also have a class called Student with list of grades:

```
public class Student, IContainer {
        public IList<int> Grades{ get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
var student = new Student();
student.Add(3); //adding grade 3 to list of student's grades
```

But i don't want to define an Add method to a Student class. Rather use my method from ActionExtensions.
Is this even possible?

Comment: You can add an extension method to an interface, but that interface would need to expose properties and/or methods you would need to implement the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You could do it like this:

```
public interface IContainer<T>
{
   IList<T> Values { get; }
}

public static class ContainerExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T>(this IContainer<T> container, T value) =>
       container.Values.Add(value);
}

public class Student : IContainer<int>
{
    public List<int> Grades { get; set; }
    IContainer<int>.Values => Grades;
}
```

You can than use it like this

```
var student = GetSomeStudent();
student.Add(3);
```